# How can I attach stainless steel utensils to aluminium posts?

Tags: kitchens

I am trying to attach aluminum posts to stainless steel eating utensils so that I can then screw the posts into my kitchen cabinets.  The directions said to use bonding glue, but I've tried JB Weld and Pro Line Fast Grab Premium Loctite, but neither work.  Would soldering be the answer or do I need to find someone to weld them?

Comment: Solder won't work.  Solder isn't for structural connections.  You need a solid mechanical fit first.

Comment: If I were making pulls from silverware, I'd drill through the stainless utensils so as to put a screw into a threaded post. OTOH, you can buy precast, utensil shaped, drawer pulls: http://www.dlawlesshardware.com/kiutknfosp.html

Comment: I believe that aluminum welding is a much more difficult type of weld than steel welding.  I'd also worry that putting two different metals in direct contact to each other would lead to corrosion.

Comment: Expecting to weld Aluminum and Stainless Steel together are like bonding oil and water. First, the two are not metals that alloy together and second, the heat difference guarantees the aluminum will be long gone by the time Stainless Steel starts to melt. I know that aluminum welding is more difficult, usually you use a TIG process to keep the aluminum from burning and it only takes a little excess heat to leave a fist sized hole. We made drift boats at one time. The answer is mechanical fasteners.

Answer (score 1):

You will have better luck brazing the stainless steel (which has nickel and chromium) to a brass or bronze post.  Brazing is a hotter form of soldering,  You might inquire if a jeweler would silver solder it for you.  Other wise, torches, special flux and special solder are needed.

A less expensive option would be a better grade of epoxy.  System 3 or some of the 3M industrial epoxies.  As Chris said, there must be a GOOD MECHANICAL fit first, the part shapes must align closely to allow the adhesive to bind.

On another note, you should try to abrade both parts in the contact area to give the adhesive a "toothing" point to grab.